# returning control to correct mvc session

Tags: spring-mvc

In our spring MVC GAE application we have a page whose form action sends the from data offsite to

```
https://secure.notarealurl.com/subver
```

They in turn return the results by calling

```
 www.anotherbogusurl.com/subver/results
```

Which the MVC controller routes to the correct controller on our side.  They generate a "session_id" which is sent both directions.

How can I get the MVC to "reconnect" to the original "user/session" (who is still waiting after the last submit) so I can tell them if they passed or failed - so they can continue accordingly?

Using their session_id I can get the user credentials and probably even the real session id but how do I get the MVC pointed back in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "they generate a session_id which is sent both directions" - is this done through a cookie, a request parameter or something else? Has anotherbogusurl.com created a session before posting data to notarealurl.com?

Comment: They generate the session_id (which is just some proprietary string)  which gets put into the outgoing form and posted to them. It is also a request parameter when it comes back to us.   And yes, the user is several pages into our site before they get to this page so there is already a session

Comment: If the user already has a session on anotherbogusurl.com then his session should naturally resume when he is be redirected to this site. The application session ID usually is returned in the form of a cookie and is automatically sent by the browser on every request. Isn't that what you observe?

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure how the MVC kept track.

Comment: Glad it's working. I added my last comment as an answer so that you can accept it and solve the question. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user already has a session on anotherbogusurl.com then his session should naturally resume when he is redirected to this site. The application session ID usually is returned in the form of a cookie and is automatically sent by the browser on every request.